# Unhandled exception. RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I have set up RabbitMQ server on my laptop using this docker image.

https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq

And command: `docker run -d --hostname rabbit-release --name rabbit-releaset -p 15672:15672 -p  5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management`

and Setting:

```
"rabbitMq": {
    "namespace": "common",
    "retries": 3,
    "retryInterval": 2,
    "username": "guest",
    "password": "guest",
    "virtualHost": "/",
    "port": 5672,
    "hostnames": [
      "rabbit-release"
    ],
    "requestTimeout": "00:00:10",
    "publishConfirmTimeout": "00:00:01",
    "recoveryInterval": "00:00:10",
    "persistentDeliveryMode": true,
    "autoCloseConnection": true,
    "automaticRecovery": true,
    "topologyRecovery": true,
    "exchange": {
      "durable": true,
      "autoDelete": false,
      "type": "Topic"
    },
    "queue": {
      "autoDelete": false,
      "durable": true,
      "exclusive": false
    }
  },
```

This is log of a container that has exited:

> Unhandled exception.
> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the
> specified endpoints were reachable  --->
> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
> ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException
> (111): Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception
> source)    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<>c.b__275_0(IAsyncResult iar)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at RabbitMQ.Client.TcpClientAdapter.ConnectAsync(String
> host, Int32 port)    at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TaskExtensions.TimeoutAfter(Task task, Int32
> millisecondsTimeout)    at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient
> socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Int32 timeout)    --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---    at
> RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver
> resolver, Func`2 selector)    at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)    at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)    at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IList`1 hostnames,
> String clientProvidedName)    at
> RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IList`1 hostnames)  at RawRabbit.Channel.ChannelFactory.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token)    at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.RawRabbitDependencyRegisterExtension.<>c.<AddRawRabbit>b__0_3(IDependencyResolver resolver)    at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.b__0()
> at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)    at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper
> executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)    at
> System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()    at
> RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSingleton>b__1(IDependencyResolver resolver)    at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.GetService(Type serviceType, Object[] additional)    at RawRabbit.DependencyInjection.SimpleDependencyInjection.GetService[TService](Object[] additional)    at RawRabbit.Instantiation.InstanceFactory.Create()    at iNRES.Common.RabbitMq.Extensions.AddRabbitMq(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)    at iNRES.Service.Common.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /app/src/iNRES.Service.Common/Startup.cs:line 116    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.ConfigureServicesDelegateBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.g__RunPipeline|0(IServiceCollection
> services)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object
> instance, IServiceCollection services)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(IServiceCollection
> services)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.ConfigureServicesDelegateBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.g__ConfigureServicesWithContainerConfiguration|0(IServiceCollection
> services)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
> services)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.Initialize()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()    at
> iNRES.Service.WaterResource.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> /app/src/iNRES.Service.Common/Program.cs:line 18

Answer (score -1):

If you're running the client code in the host, the `--hostname` docker option has no effect, so you'd need to use `localhost` instead of `rabbit-release` in the client code.